# NSDateFormatter dateFromString format string issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I encountered a small problem today: I receive a couple of dates (NSString) from a web server. To use those dates correctly they need to be parsed into NSDate objects, for which I'm using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss";
return [formatter dateFromString:dateString]
```

The dates I am receiving are in the following format e.g.: @"02.06.2015 13:31:24".

My problem is that the above code returns nil. I think the issue probably is that I don't have the correct format string, which I have not been able to get right..

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: try to use [NSDate date] instead of your dateString and tell me what u get ?

Comment: Did you read the Apple tech note on date parsing with formats?

Comment: You seem to be missing a y in the year section...

Comment: @DavidSilverFarmer  your problem solved or not.

Comment: While you're missing a 'y' in the year format, it works fine with me. I thus doubt the correctness of the format you're receiving.

Comment: Count the y's in the year format!

Comment: Don't forget the 12/24 "feechure".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a 'y' in your format. It should be:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
return [formatter dateFromString:dateString]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code -

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
return [formatter dateFromString:dateString]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSDate *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",string];
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return myDate;
}
```

Call it wherever required :)

```
[self getDateFromString:@"13.07.2013 16:22:11"];
```